# Replace all occurrences of a string preceded by specific pattern using java

Tags: java, regex

I have gone though various questions posted in stack overflow to get solution of my question, but I couldn't find the exact match.  Hence asking this.

I have a pattern as follows:

```
    :20: LAIDKZPABCL90165LZJABC
    :90: LZ,90509LAOABCXL,XKPA;AOLZ
    :90C: KDOLASABC9080690ABD
    :90D: ABDBABC906AODIPALKD
    :90L: AND9011112XXXADABC
    :90: AKLZPDOAMXNA,;POAS
```

In the above string I have to replace all (or atleast first) the occurrences of string "ABC" to "XYZ" which are preceded by ":90C:" or ":90D:".  I have the following solution which replaces the first occurrence is working fine.

```
    String data; // Let data be the string as mentioned above
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(:9(0(C|D)):).*?ABC");
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(data);
    int endIndex = -1;
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(buf2);
    System.out.println(buf.toString());
    while(matcher.find()){
        endIndex = matcher.end();
        buf.replace(endIndex-3, endIndex, "XYZ");

    }
    System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

Here I am getting the proper result.  Its replacing the first occurrence of "ABC" with "XYZ" which are preceded by either :90C: or :90D:.

Is there any precise solution to achieve this?  I am not able to use lookbehind as I am not sure of the position of ABC in the data. Need solution if possible to replace all (preceded by :90C: or :90D: using regex.  I think replace all is not possible I guess, as we are not sure of boundary.  Please help me out on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses lookahead,

```
(?=:90C:|:90D:)(.*?)ABC(\\S+)
```

Just replace the matched characters with `$1XYZ$2`.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/7)

Comment: Its working as expected.  Is there any way to replace all occurrences of ABC preceded by :90C: or :90D: